# How to hide optgroup/option elements?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select, optgroup

Is there a way to hide `option` or `optgroup` HTML elements? I've tried calling `hide()` in jQuery, and also using regular Javascript to set `style.display='none'`.

It works in Firefox but not in any other browsers. Actually removing them from the DOM *does* work, so perhaps there's a way to save each DOM element when it's removed, and reinsert them in the same place?

My HTML is like this:

```
<select name="propsearch[area]" id="propsearch_area">
    <option value="0">- Any -</option>
    <optgroup label="Bristol">
        <option  value="Hotwells">Hotwells</option>
        <option  value="Montpelier">Montpelier</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Cardiff">
        <option  value="Heath">Heath</option>
        <option  value="Roath">Roath</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Exeter">
        <option  value="Pennsylvania Road">Pennsylvania Road</option>
        <option  value="Lower North Street">Lower North Street</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Swansea">
        <option  value="Brynmill">Brynmill</option>
        <option  value="Uplands">Uplands</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: In case R0MANARMY is correct and you're fine with just disabling them, `$('optgroup[label=Swansea]').attr('disabled', true)` seems to work fine.

Comment: @MaxShawabkeh The `disabled` attribute on `<option>` only works from IE8 onwards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured that this solution works fine for me:

Make another select e.g.

```
$("#footer_canvas").after('<select id="parkingLot"></select>');
```

then hide it

```
$("#parkingLot").hide();
```

When you want to 'hide' some optgroup, just 'park' it in this hidden select.

```
$('#VehicleVehicleCategoryId optgroup[label="kategorie L"]').appendTo("#parkingLot");
```

Same way you can make it visible.
This is just the snippets of my solution, that works fine for me.

Comment: Another way would be to just store the data in a JSON object that you can manipulate instead of the hidden select.