# Hide Options from Multiple Selection Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, multipleselection

I need to hide certain options from Multiple selection box using Javascript. I can't got for jQuery, and I am not allowed to.

I have one more dropdown box, I am calling a js function which will be called upon change of the value. The js function will control the options of another multiple select options box, where I need to hide (not remove) options based on dropdown box value.

Any simple js function?

http://jsfiddle.net/zz3dg/

Edit:
tried

```
fastInternet.options[i].style.display = 'none';
fastInternet.options[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Didn't work :(

Comment: See if this post helps:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731668/how-to-hide-optgroup-option-elements

Comment: Nothing worked. can any one write complete Js here. I am getting down for every new thread popping up with solution that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using your jsFiddle link but some of the stuff there was prevented the method from working correctly.

I made some modifications and it's working perfectly:

html:

```
<select id="option_two" multiple>        
  <option value="VOIP">VOIP</option>         
  <option value="BDS">BDS</option>          
  <option value="DMW">DMW</option>          
  <option value="IDTV">IDTV</option>          
  <option value="P3TR">P3TR</option> 
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
 var fastInternet = document.getElementById('option_two');

 for ( var i = 0; i < fastInternet.options.length; i++) {
     var value = fastInternet.options[i].value;

     if(value == 'IDTV' || value == 'P3TR'){
        fastInternet.options[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
     }
 }​
```

In JsFiddle, make sure that the framework is set to onLoad and No-Library(pure JS)
In chrome it worked. But I got some problems in IE though :/

Comment: that's the problem. IE is my fist preference and I need to make it work for IE.

Comment: @Nitin The closest I got to solving your problem is this: http://jsfiddle.net/BMs8D/4/

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED:**

**New Suggestion:**

What about to make it `disable`

```
fastInternet.options[i].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")
```

And then hide it by using following CSS:

```
select option[disabled] {
    display: none; /* worked in firefox*/
    visibility: hidden; /* worked in chrome*/
}
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/v3AWf/)

It might help!

**OLD Suggestion:**

Try to use

```
 fastInternet.remove(options[i])
```

Comment: Removing will delete the option from dropdown, which shouldn't happen. It should be just hidden for certain conditions and should be visible for other condtions

Comment: @Nitin Gurram: What about to make it `disable`, updated my answer.

Comment: Nope, Just disable the options in IE8

Comment: might be using jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271503/hide-options-in-a-select-list-using-jquery     OR     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031740/hide-select-option-in-ie-using-jquery

Comment: Nothing worked. can any one write complete Js here. I am getting down for every new thread popping up with solution that doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Adding `display:none` worked for me. But I did it via css.

Have build an example. Check it [here](http://jsbin.com/ujezaf/3)

Dont have chrome installed to test. But I guess `visibility:hidden` should work.