# Collapse/expand optgroups

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to expand or collapse optgroups?
I have VERY long lists that I have to load into the list and it makes it difficult to look for certain items this way.
Really hope so and if so, Thanks in advance.

Here is a similar solution  -  **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nel_mo/gad27q4b/5/)**.
Not a optgroup, but can be adapted to act in a similar way.

> ```
> $(".header").click(function () {
>     $header = $(this);
>     $content = $header.next();
>     $content.slideToggle(200, function () {
>         $('.contentCol', this).fadeToggle(400);
>     });
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [Select2](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2). Also, you may refer to this [Stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731668/how-to-hide-optgroup-option-elements).