# Show all select box options that don't contain the value hello_

Tags: jquery

So I want to be able to hide all the options and then show only the ones that don't include `hello_` in their value. This includes `hello_bye`, `hello_hello` etc. Anything that starts with `hello_`

This is what I have so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#metakeyselect > option").hide();
    jQuery("#metakeyselect > option[//what goes here?//]").show();
});
```

How do I show everything BUT options with values including hello_?

Comment: By "value" you mean the `value` attribute or the text content of the option element?

Comment: option[value='blah'] value

Comment: Ah, then go with Felix's answer.

Comment: @Zenith Because I only pasted part of the problem. I'm actually fooling around with WordPress's core in my theme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "hide" the ones whose value start with `hello_` using the [*attribute-starts-with* selector](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2464706/alex-morrise).

As [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2464706/alex-morrise) pointed out correctly, not all browsers let you hide option elements though (see also [How to hide optgroup/option elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2731668)). But you can remove them:

```
var hidden_options = jQuery("#metakeyselect > option[value^=hello_]").remove();
```

or disable them:

```
jQuery("#metakeyselect > option[value^=hello_]").prop('disabled', true);
```

depending on what else you want to do with them.

Comment: so does this work like a regex where anything that starts with `hello_` will be removed?

Comment: @Edmund: Every option element whose value attribute starts with `hello_` will be removed, yes.

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

**Elements that contain `hello_`**:

```
$("#metakeyselect > option:contains('hello_')")
```

**Elements that do not contain `hello_`**:

```
$("#metakeyselect > option:not(:contains('hello_'))")
```

Comment: this won't check that condition:  "Anything that starts"

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var options = $('#metakeyselect > option');
    var contains = "hello_";

    options.each(function() {
        if($(this).val().indexOf(contains) != -1){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#metakeyselect > option").remove();
    $("#metakeyselect > option[value*='hello_']").show();
});
```

You will need to use remove() for options.