# Jquery Multi select - How to collapse a opt group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using the Jquery multi select tool located here http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget and I got everything working great. I have a very long list of items and divded by optgroups. You have to scroll quite a lot of get to the last item so im wondering if theres a way to collapse the opt group by default?

I looked at documentation regarding this script but didn't see any functions to collapse by optgroup.

```
                <select name="selSea" id="selSeaShells" size="5" multiple="multiple" onchange="loopSelected()">
                    <optgroup label="Group 1"/>
                        <option value="test">test</option>
                        <option value="test1">test1</option>
                        <option value="test2">test2</option>
                        <option value="test3">test3</option>
                    <optgroup label="Group2"/>
                        <option value="test">test</option>
                        <option value="test1">test1</option>
                        <option value="test2">test2</option>
                        <option value="test3">test3</option>
                        <option value="test4">test4</option>
                    <optgroup label="Group3"/>
                        <option value="test">test</option>
                        <option value="test1">test1</option>
                        <option value="test2">test2</option>
                        <option value="test3">test3</option>
                        <option value="test4">test4</option>    
                 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Select2](https://github.com/select2/select2). Also, you may refer to this [Stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731668/how-to-hide-optgroup-option-elements).

**Using Select2:**

In your CSS, hide the sub results by default:

```
.select2-result-sub > li.select2-result {
    display: none;
}
```

Then add this to your Javascript file:

```
$('.select2-results').on('click', 'li', function(){
    $(this).find('li').show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, i am going trough the documentation for Select2 but don't see anything about collapsible optgroups? Would you have any ideas about that? I would gladly switch if it does offer that functionality built in.

Comment: Great ill give this a try, working on replacing my old multiselect script.